# Search for the first show of a expression in text file and copy it to the clipboard -using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a bat file that will search for a specific expression in a text file and copy it to my clipboard,

Example:

I want to search in this file **C:\test.log** The **first**  instance of:

```
TestSerialNumber = %%%%%%%%%
```

(The %%%%%%%% are 8 numbers, for example: TestSerialNumber = 44436643, the numbers change)

And copy only the numbers to the clipboard

I got entangled with finding the  first show.

I would appreciate help

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve] of your own coding attempts! Furthermore, please take the [tour], visit the [help] to learn [ask]!

Comment: Shraga, can you please confirm whether you want whatever is assigned, to always the first instance of `TestSerialNumber`? The first non empty value assigned to it? The first eight digit value assigned? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%a in ('findstr TestSerialNumber c:\test.log') do echo %%a | clip
```

Comment: Let me suggest to change the expression `findstr TestSerialNumber c:\test.log` to `findstr /C:"^TestSerialNumber  *=  *[0-9][0-9]*$" C:\test.log`…

Comment: Your code also does not provide a solution to the question asked. The question asks for the first value for `TestSerialNumber` not the last. Please reread the question and modify your code accordingly.